# pydlm error after adding auto regression terms

Tags: python, time-series

```
from pydlm import dlm, trend, seasonality, autoReg

global simple_dlm
tempResult=[]
finalDataFrame=updatedDataFrame
finalDataFrame=finalDataFrame.loc[:, (finalDataFrame != 
finalDataFrame.ix[0]).any()] 
linear_trend = trend(degree=1, name='linear_trend', discount=0.99, 
w=1e7)
seasonal24 = seasonality(period=24, name='seasonal24', discount=0.99, 
w=1e7)
AR1 = autoReg(degree=1,data=finalDataFrame['Speciality'], 
discount=0.99, name='ar3', w=1e7)
AR3 = autoReg(degree=3,data=finalDataFrame['Speciality'], 
discount=0.99, name='ar1', w=1e7)

simple_dlm = 
dlm(finalDataFrame.values.tolist())+linear_trend+seasonal24+AR3+ AR1
simple_dlm.fitForwardFilter()
simple_dlm.fitBackwardSmoother()
simple_dlm.fit()
predicted=simple_dlm.predictN(date=simple_dlm.n-1,N=72)
```

On predictN function I am getting error 'dlm' object has no attribute 'predictStatus. On excluding the autoReg terms the models is executing,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for raising the issue. The bug has been fixed in the current Github version of `pydlm`.
https://github.com/wwrechard/pydlm

Thanks!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17470083)

Comment: @Jonathon If this was a library bug, this does answer the question. It may not be relevant to the OP to know exactly what caused the bug, only that it has been fixed. In which case it is hard to add more details to the answer.

Comment: Would best be recorded as a comment.